# Redirect to current URL, but replace string?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

So I have a working redirect that currently sends customers to my homepage if they select a different city from a drop-down select. This changes some custom user meta data and uses that to determine when a redirect should occur. Simple enough.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display !== 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == true) {
        header('Location: example.com');
        }
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display == 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == false) {
        header('Location: example.com/chicago/');
        }
```

What I would like to achieve is, if the customer is on the shop page, the I can redirect them to the CURRENT page they are on (not the homepage), but simply replace the city name with `strpos` or something similar... basically call the current URL and only replace the name of the city, regardless of where in the URL that string is.

Something like:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display !== 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == true) {
            header('Location: example.com');
            }
        if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display == 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == false) {
            header('Location: GET CURRENT URL & REPLACE CURRENT CITY (using a list of cities) OR ADD 'CHICAGO' AFTER DOMAIN IF ONE DOESN'T EXIST ');
            }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (remove type declarations if using < PHP 7+):

```
function get_current_url( array $cities, string $target_city ): string {

    // Get protocol.
    $url = ( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? 'https://' : 'http://' );

    // Get URL parts.
    $port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
    $name = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    $uri  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // Check all cities in the array and replace if found.
    foreach ( $cities as $city ) {
        $uri = str_replace( $city, $target_city, $uri );
    }

    // Build URL with matching port.
    $url .= ( $port !== '80' ? $name . ':' . $port . $uri : $name . $uri );

    // Return escaped URL.
    return esc_url( $url );

}
```

And then in your code:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display !== 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == true) {
    header('Location: example.com');
}

// Fill array with possible cities.
$cities = array( 'london', 'new-york', );

if ( is_user_logged_in() && $metalocation_display == 'chicago' && strpos($url,'chicago') == false) {
    header('Location: ' . get_current_url( $cities, 'chicago' ) );
}
```

Obviously be sure to prefix the function though.

Comment: If you don't need the `$cities` array for anything else, then you could also just put it inside the function and use `get_current_url( 'chicago' )` in the main code.